# Remove return key or newline in txt file before import in excel (vba)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba script that brings in a .csv file and sorts it in excel. However there are some carriage returns on the end column and this is adding newlines in the import. I can fix this manually by going to the text file and replacing \n with "". But i would like this to be done automatically in the script before it is imported.

Here is my current script to import the text file:

```
For rep1 = 8 To 8

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, pctCompl As Integer, myint As Integer

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim file_name As String
Dim file_name2 As String
Dim row_number As String
Dim output_sheet As String
Dim hour As String
Dim day As String
Dim month As String
Dim project As String

Set ws = Worksheets("Master")
Set ws1 = Worksheets("RAW_Data")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("BOM")

file_name = Sheets("Master").Range("F" & rep1).Value
file_name2 = Sheets("Master").Range("G" & rep1).Value
output_sheet = Sheets("Master").Range("L" & rep1).Value
row_number = Sheets("Master").Range("M" & rep1).Value
hour = Format(Sheets("Master").Range("I" & rep1).Value, "00")
day = Sheets("Master").Range("K" & rep1).Value
month = Sheets("Master").Range("J" & rep1).Value
project = Sheets("Master").Range("B2").Value

ws1.Activate
Columns("A:A").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

ws.Activate

aa = file_name2 & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & Format(Time, "Hh")

With Sheets(output_sheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" +        file_name + "\" + month + "\" + day + "\" + file_name2 & Format(Date,  "yyyymmdd") & "_" & hour & ".txt",  Destination:=Sheets(output_sheet).Range("$A$" + row_number))
    .Name = file_name & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & Format(Time,  "Hh")
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "~"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 2, 9, 2, 2, 2, 2)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
    Next rep1

ws1.Activate
lastrow = Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Cells.Replace What:="true", Replacement:="TRUE", LookAt:=xlPart, _
searchorder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

Cells.Replace What:="false", Replacement:="FALSE", LookAt:=xlPart, _
searchorder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

ws1.Columns("A:AZ").EntireColumn.AutoFit

ws2.UsedRange.ClearContents
ws2.Range("A1:G" & lastrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 7)).Value
ws2.Range("N1:O" & lastrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 8), Cells(lastrow, 9)).Value
ws2.Range("Y1:Y" & lastrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(lastrow, 11)).Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to open the text file with something like an file system object, then `replace()` the character(s) you need, then write back to a temporary file and use that as an input. All of these steps are easily googleable, but if you get stuck, reply to this and I'll edit my post with more detail.